# Reputation change notifications in iOS app feed don't always behave as expected

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Using the following two reputation change items as an example…

[image: reputation change items with unexpected behaviour]

…I noticed this set of issues:

1. The reputation changes should probably be rolled up into a single line*
2. The +5 on my question links me to [Arie Litovsky's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220561) (or maybe just the answers tab), even though the reputation gain was on the question
3. The +2 for accepting the answer doesn't link anywhere; tapping on it does nothing

This seems to only be an issue when the two events are displayed together. In other instances where the reputation events are on their own, a +2 event takes me to the accepted answer, and a +5 event takes me to the question as expected.

If the events are paired but happen in the reverse order (i.e. the +2 event comes after reputation on the question), then the behaviour is reversed – the +2 event links to the question and the +5 event doesn't do anything when tapped.

<sub>*the site itself is [guilty of not doing this too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164062/reputation-from-accepting-answer-isnt-grouped-correctly-when-viewed-by-post), so if it's a consistency thing I can live with that</sub>

Comment: I tried going through my feed and I can't replicate.  On rep for questions, it's taking me to questions, on rep for answers, it's scrolling down to my answer.

Comment: It does sound like an indexing problem though.  It would make sense for your +2 to take you to the accepted item.

Comment: @BrianNickel Hm, you're right. It works correctly for other instances where I received reputation for the question, so perhaps it being displayed with the +2 for accepting is the problem.

Comment: @BrianNickel I tested further and clarified the report, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yep, found the bad code doing a bad thing.  Fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.  The perils of using `indexOf` (and family).